# SQL three table joins using two ids and another column

Tags: sql

I have three tables

```
t1    t2     t3
```

I want to select data from only two of the tables but need the ids and columns from other tables for reference.

How to select data from t3  and t2

```
WHERE t1.id = t2.id = t3.id
  AND t1.fid = t2.fid = t3.fid 
  AND t1.type = 'abc'
```

`id` column will be the same value for all tables. `fid` column will have incremental fid's but need the ones where t1.type = 'abc' also

Would this work?

```
select data 
from t3 

select data 
from t2 
join on t1.id = t2.id and t2.id = t3.id 
join on t1.fid = t2.fid and t2.fid = t3.fid and t1.type = 'abc'
where id = 1
```

Comment: You ask: "Would this work?"  What happens when you try it?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really make it clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, this kind of problem can be solved using `EXISTS` as follows:

```
select data 
from t2 
join t1 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.fid = t2.fid
where exists (select 1 from t3 where t2.id = t3.id and t2.fid = t3.fid)
  and t1.type = 'abc'
  and t1.id = 1
```

Comment: I am wondering about the clauses where t(x)fid = t(y)fid. fid column is the primary key and is incremental on each row. So will this get everything of type xyz plus all different id's?

Comment: also for this clause: select 1 from t3; Did you mean select data from t3?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```sql
select columns_that_you_want 
from t1 x
inner join t2 y on x.id = y.id
inner join t3 z on y.id = z.id
where x.type = 'abc'
;
```

This will join the three tables, and filter just the type `'abc'` that you want from table t1. Also you can add more filter on the where clause in case you need to filter more the result.